# Outlets not showing in file owners

Tags: xcode, ios7

I create a class which subclass of UITableViewCell with xib created, when running , error shows:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SYGPlayerTableViewCell" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

So I try to connect the view outlet , but I found the outlets not showing, It is really wired since it is ok in another file. [image: bad case]

[image: good case]

--problem resolved by change File Owner's custom class to "UIViewController"

[image: resolved]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you are instantiating a `UITableViewCell`, there's no File Owner and the outlets go directly to the cell instance, named `Player Table View Cell` in your example.

'File owner' references the object that is instantiating the XIB, usually is a `UIViewController`, that instantiates its view in the XIB and references all the outlets to itself using the 'File owner'. But that doesn't make sense if all the objects are declared directly in the XIB.

Comment: Yes, you are right ,problem resolved when I change the File Owner's "Custom class" to "UIViewController". thanks!